# MSCTF.dll complains 'An assertion failure has occurred'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, qt5

I'm developing application on Win11 with Win10 SDK, here is my environment:

- MSVC v142
- Win10 SDK(10.0.19041.0)
- PCL 1.12.1
- OpenCV 4.8.0
- Qt 5.15.2

When I run my application from Qt Creator in debug mode, it complains:

```
clientcore\windows\advcore\ctf\uim\tim.cpp(800)\MSCTF.dll!00007FFA625262B9: 
(caller: 00007FFA62526EEC) LogHr(1) tid(267c) 8007029C 
An assertion failure has occurred.
```

Minimal example:

***header***

```
#ifndef MINIMAL_H
#define MINIMAL_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
  class Minimal;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Minimal : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Minimal(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~Minimal();

private:
  bool readPcd(const QString &file, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr &cloud);

  bool readImage(const QString &file, cv::Mat &image);

  Ui::Minimal *ui;
};
#endif // MINIMAL_H
```

***source***

```
#include "minimal.h"
#include "./ui_minimal.h"
#include <QDebug>

Minimal::Minimal(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Minimal)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud;
  readPcd("..\\example_data\\20210209152054.pcd", cloud);
  qDebug() << "cloud size is " << cloud->points.size();

  cv::Mat image;
  readImage("..\\example_data\\20210209152054.jpg", image);
  qDebug() << "image size is " << image.cols << " x " << image.rows;
}

Minimal::~Minimal()
{
  delete ui;
}

bool Minimal::readPcd(const QString &file, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr &cloud)
{
  cloud.reset(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile(file.toStdString(), *cloud) == -1)
  {
    std::cout << "read pcd file error " << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

bool Minimal::readImage(const QString &file, cv::Mat &image)
{
  image = cv::imread(file.toStdString());
  return (!image.empty());
}
```

===== Updated =====
add main.cpp created by qtcreator

***main.cpp***

```cpp
#include "minimal.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    const QStringList uiLanguages = QLocale::system().uiLanguages();
    for (const QString &locale : uiLanguages) {
        const QString baseName = "Minimal_" + QLocale(locale).name();
        if (translator.load(":/i18n/" + baseName)) {
            a.installTranslator(&translator);
            break;
        }
    }
    Minimal w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Probably what you should do first is use a debugger.

Comment: @john From my build kits of QtCreator, I'm sure it is using a debugger from my `Windows Kits` install directory, named cdb.exe

Comment: Since you are using a debugger, what is the stack backtrace when the assert triggers?

Comment: @Eljay I tried add a breakpoint in line `ui->setupUi(this);` , finally, it won't print `MSCTF.dll ...` error message before the execution of line ` w.show();` which is from main.cpp when we create a minimal example automatically by qtcreator. I Update my question by main.cpp

Comment: It is a debug message generated by msctf.dll itself.  0x8007029C simply means "assertion failure", no context what is actually getting asserted.  Compare to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSCTFdll-timcpp-An-assertion-failure-h/10513796?space=41&sort=newest&viewtype=all).  It *could* be a sign of things going wrong, but not necessarily the case.  MSCTF is not a critical system service. 
 Unless you can demonstrate failure in your own code, there is no decent way to diagnose the issue.  Best to keep going.

Comment: Things are ok when this assertion message showed up.I don't think I can deal with it nether. Hope it won't bother me further. Thanks guys anyway.

Comment: I think this might be on Microsoft's end or something, as I get the following 2 lines printed to my output window for every app I run, even just an empty console project, using Visual Studio C++ in Windows 11:

clientcore\windows\advcore\ctf\uim\tim.cpp(800)\MSCTF.dll!771C230A: (caller: 771BDAC0) LogHr(1) tid(184c) 8007029C An assertion failure has occurred.
clientcore\windows\advcore\ctf\uim\tim.cpp(800)\MSCTF.dll!771C230A: (caller: 771BDAC0) LogHr(2) tid(184c) 8007029C An assertion failure has occurred.

I found this question searching for what the heck they mean.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an issue with your program, it's a bug with the new "shell handwriting" feature (MTestAbSh1, 41799415) that's currently in experiment. You can download [ViVeTool](https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe) to check whether the feature is enabled:

```bash
vivetool /query /id:41799415
```

If you're like me, this feature is probably set to "Experiment" meaning it's enabled on your machine for testing. You can disable it with:

```bash
vivetool /disable /id:41799415
```

Which will manually override it to disable the feature. This doesn't take effect immediately, and you'll need to restart afterward. Afterward, the assertion failure should no longer appear.

I ran into this issue a month or so ago and have reported this issue through a couple different avenues. I wrote up some of my process for decompiling and debugging MSCTF.dll [on twitter](https://twitter.com/david_koloski/status/1731511565076033956).